# Send parameters via POST HTTPRequest (appcelerator titanium)

Tags: json, post, xmlhttprequest, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have created a page on my server (index.php) that when access by the app (via appcelerator titanium) via createHTTPClient (app.js and login.js), returns a JSON string. But i have problems when i login and send parameters via POST HTTPRequest.

**index.php :**

```
<?php
class Connect{
public function login($username, $password){
    $db = mysqli_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com", "a8324766_user", "**********", "a8324766_db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM users 
            WHERE username ='$username'
            AND   password = '$password'";
    $req = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req);

    if(isset($data['username'])&& !empty($data['username']) && isset($data['password'])&& !empty($data['password'])){
            if (mysqli_num_rows($req) > 0){
                $response = array(
                    "logged" => true,
                    "name" => $data['name'],
                    "email" => $data['email']);  
            echo json_encode($response);   
                 }
    else
    {
        // Else the username and/or password was invalid! Create an array, json_encode it and echo it out
        $response = array(
            "logged" => false,
            "message" => 'Invalid Username and/or Password'
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    }else{
            echo "login ou mot de passe est incorrecte";
    }

}
}

$user = new Connect();
$user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

?>
```

**app.js :**

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#fff');
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var login = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'User Authentication Demo',
    tabBarHidden:true,
    url:'login.js'
});

var loginTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title:"Login",
    window:login
});

tabGroup.addTab(loginTab);
tabGroup.open();
```

**login.js :**

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:10,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Username',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(username);

var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:60,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Password',
passwordMask:true,
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(password);

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:'Login',
top:110,
width:90,
height:35,
borderRadius:1,
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
});
win.add(loginBtn);

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({timeout:50000});

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
    var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);

    if (response.logged == true){
        alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
    } else {
        alert(response.message);
    }

};

xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Error >>>> ' + JSON.stringify(e));
};    

loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    xhr.open("POST","http://lahcene.comli.com/index.php");
    var params = {
        username: username.value,
        password: password.value
    };
    alert(username.value);
    alert(password.value);
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type','application/json' );
    xhr.send(params);
});
```

The result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfByi.png

The result whene i login with username and password :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qm1m.png

any idea please.

Comment: It looks like you are using Opera to debug your mobile web app using Titanium.  This should be an issue with your web browser 'securing' you from a cross-domain request.  This is indicated by the XMLHttpRequest error.  In Chrome there is a way to override this safety feature of your browser.  This should be a Opera issue and not Titanium.  The web browser you are using is rejecting the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simply answer for fix cross-domain is a LAMP or use Domain Server at Website:

[Install Lamp](http://lamphowto.com/) (Linux) , [Install Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) (Mac OS) & [Install Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html) (Windows)

When you install this software bundle, use your html in it :)

1º You have a problem in your send due to Content-Type must be **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

2º Your function php login() return a JSON or String... must be JSON always because you use JSON.parse at xhr.onload().

`echo "login ou mot de passe est incorrecte";` change to

```
$response = array(
   "logged" => false,
   "message" => 'login ou mot de passe est incorrecte'
);
echo json_encode($response);
```